# sqlceengine.compact method alternative

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

is there an alternative way to save a database file other than using sqlceengine.compact method ?
this is my code :

```
 Dim engine As New SqlCeEngine("Data Source = " + Path + databasename)
            If Directory.Exists("\" & otherPath) Then
                If File.Exists("\" & otherPath & "\" databasename) Then
                    File.Delete("\" & otherPath & "\" databasename)
                End If
                engine.Compact("Data Source= \" & otherPath & "\" databasename)
            end if ...
```

compact doesn't work and i need an other way to save the database file

thanks in advence :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.IO.File.Copy`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.